# Count all unique values in list + their Total quantity and Total price per Item cost

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to have the following:

- List of unique values from another list
- Total occurrences of that value in the other list
- Total price of the items **per Item cost**

Play here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11EHm7N4iK8N9oLb8VXrycTwPVHLmoBay4Z6dugaOr7I/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

As [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069641/count-all-unique-values-in-list-their-total-quantity-and-total-price-per-item/62070751#comment109805114_62070751):

***"How about ordering the list in Item Cost from highest to lowest?"***

```
=QUERY(A1:C9,"select A, sum(B), sum(B)*C where A is not null 
               group by A, C order by sum(B)*C desc label sum(B) 'Total Quantity', sum(B)*C 'Item Cost'" )
```

---

**Original answer**

Please use the following formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C9,"select A, sum(B), sum(B)*C where A is not null 
               group by A, C label sum(B) 'Total Quantity', sum(B)*C 'Item Cost'" )
```

*(adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Thanks, this is great! How about ordering the list in Item Cost from highest to lowest? You can edit your formula in cell E25: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11EHm7N4iK8N9oLb8VXrycTwPVHLmoBay4Z6dugaOr7I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And if I wanted to order by total quantity, is there a simple modification to the formula? Thanks again! I honestly have to idea what to do!

Comment: *"And if I wanted to order by total quantity, is there a simple modification to the formula?"* Couldn't be simpler. See that `order by` in the formula? After that follows the column to order by. Try changing it. Also try `desc` for descending and `asc` for ascending. Also **do read** [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). I believe you will figure it out. If not, let us know.

Comment: Hi again, I noticed that if the Item Cost is different, but the Item Name is the same, the formula adds a new line for the item - https://cdn.zappy.app/7ffb7f80498167fee543849b94f9cbe8.png. Over time, item cost change with inflation, but I want to show the total quanity and cost for items with same name.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Please do realize that by editing data in your sheet and then [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62069641/3), **you created a totally different question** in need of a new, different formula. This can be really confusing for future users. Especially since you provide no data within the question. I would suggest you revert everything (sheet, accepted answer, question) as in the [previous state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62069641/2). Following that, create a new question (where cost changes over time) and let me know here. There is a solution.

Comment: No worries! Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347526/count-all-unique-values-in-list-their-total-quantity-and-total-price-per-item

Comment: Answer's in the box :)

Answer (score 2):

Modify this example for your requirements.

Query:

`=QUERY (A2:B7,"select A,sum(B) group by A")`

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is you should try first and come up with what you have tried/
Your output with formulas is ready in a same sheet please let me know if you have any doubt about it.

Item Name are under the range E13:E16 used this formula in cell F13 for count and dragged it out upto F16  **=sumifs(B$2:B$7,A$2:A$7,E13)**

Used this formula under the cell G13 and dragged it up to G16 for cost =vlookup(E13,A$2:C$7,3,False)*F13

Those changes have a restricted access to edit for me and you only.