# Count all unique values in list + their Total quantity and Total price per Item cost (where cost changes over time)

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to have the following:

- List of unique values from another list
- Total occurrences of that value in the other list
- Total price of the items

Cost changes over time, so this must count towards the total quantity of the value.

Play here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CCwoBxXYGPpR3Fog7gtyQXfH_soaZBKBHvxeikFnfzI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the prices may change over time, the formula used in your previous [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62070751/1527780) cannot be used.

Instead, please use the following formula which takes into account the price change.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:C,"select A, sum(B), sum(B)*C where A is not null group by A, C" ), 
         "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) group by Col1 order by sum(Col3) desc label sum(Col2) 'Total Quantity', sum(Col3) 'Item Cost' ")
```

[image: Total cost of products when price changing over time]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)